# How many functions $f:\{1,2,3,4,5\}\to\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ there are such that: $f^{-1}(\{1,2,3\})=\{2,3,4,5\}$and $f^{-1}(\{2,3,5\})=\{4,5\}$?

Tags: functions

How many functions $f:\{1,2,3,4,5\}\to\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ there are such that:
$f^{-1}(\{1,2,3\})=\{2,3,4,5\}$and $f^{-1}(\{2,3,5\})=\{4,5\}$?

I know that if the domain has 5 elements and the codomain has 5 elements than there are $5^5$ functions that can be done but I do not know how to find out how many of them satisfy that conditions.

Comment: What is a "domeniul", and what is a "codomomenium"?

Comment: Presumably they are the function's doman and codomain.

Comment: Hint: can you use the given information to calculate $f^{-1}(\{1\})$ and $f^{-1}(\{2,3\})$ and $f^{-1}(\{5\})$? Would that help you calculate how many possibilities there are for each of $f(1)$, $f(2)$, $f(3)$, $f(4)$, and $f(5)$?

Comment: I do not think that.How can the given Information help me to calculate that?

Comment: Could you please give me one more hint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that you can get a lot of information from $f^{-1}(\{1,2,3\})=\{2,3,4,5\}$ and $f^{-1}(\{2,3,5\})=\{4,5\}$ .

Our first condition gives us that $f(2),f(3),f(4),f(5)\in\{1,2,3\}$ and $f(1)\notin \{1,2,3\}$. Our second condition gives us that $f(4),f(5)\in\{2,3,5\}$ and $f(1),f(2),f(3)\notin \{2,3,5\}$.

Let us examine each value:

- $f(1)=4$ is the only possible option
- $f(2)=1$ is the only possible option
- $f(3)=1$ is the only possible option
- $f(4)$ can be $2$ or $3$
- $f(5)$ can be $2$ or $3$

So you have $4$ possible functions.